# Custom JOLT Transformation with Mapping

Tags: java, json, jolt

It is possible to make this kind of Json Transformation using JOLT or other java api, and get the mapping result after transformation

***Example***

- name   : is a name of person
- parent : is also a name of person

update all persons ( name and parent ) from **Paul** to **Evan**

**Input**

```
{
   "persons":[
      {
         "name":"Paul",
         "adress":"abcd",
         "parent":"Chris"
      },
      {
         "name":"Jean",
         "adress":"abcd",
         "parent":"Paul"
      }
   ]
}
```

**output**

```
{
   "persons":[
      {
         "name":"Evan",
         "adress":"abcd",
         "parent":"Chris"
      },
      {
         "name":"Jean",
         "adress":"abcd",
         "parent":"Evan"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can someone help to write the spec of this Transformation, and how we can get the mapping result after Transformation

mapping ( Paul -> Evan )

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is using this spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "persons": {
        "*": {
          "name": {
            "Paul": {
              "#Evan": "persons.[&3].name"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,name)": "persons.[&3].name"
            }
          },
          "parent": {
            "Paul": {
              "#Evan": "persons.[&3].parent"
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,parent)": "persons.[&3].parent"
            }
          },
          "*": "persons.[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```